# Cambiar un valor string a un entero

Tags: python, django, ajax

Con el siguiente código quiero hacer una validación donde valide si un dato que voy a ingresar es mayor a otro que ya tengo, si es así, debe salir un mensaje de error.

Esto es lo que me aparece como ven el valor `celda` lo toma como un `string`, entonces necesito convertirlo a entero para poder hacer la comparación.

```
Object
TTC
:
-25
celda // <--
:
"1"
valido
:
true
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
  celda = request.POST.get('bonches', None)
        TC = Clasificacion.objects.filter(fecha=date.today()).aggregate(total=Sum('tabacos'))['total']
        TB = Boncheo.objects.filter(fecha=date.today()).aggregate(total=Sum('bonches'))['total']
        TN = Nacional.objects.filter(fecha=date.today()).aggregate(total=Sum('bonches'))['total']

        if TC == None:
            TTC = 0
        elif TB == None and TN == None:
            TTC = TC
        elif TB == None and TN != None:
            TTC = TC - TN
        elif TB != None and TN == None:
            TTC = TC - TB
        else:
            TTC = TC - TB - TN

        if celda < TTC:
            valido = False
        else: 
            valido = True
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'valido': valido , 'celda' : celda , 'TTC' : TTC}), content_type='application/json')
```

Esta es mi plantilla:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="cerrarmodal" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
    <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Nuevo Boncheo</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="formatolinea" method="post" name="nboncheo" id="nboncheo" action='{% url "nuevobonche" %}'
        onsubmit="return boncheo();">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label>Bonchador</label>
            <select required="" name="boncheador" required="">
                <option>Nombre del bonchador</option>
                {% for obj in bonchador %}
                <option>{{obj.nombre}} {{obj.apellidos}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensajebr" style='display: none;'>Seleccione el nombre del bonchador</div>
            <label>Variedad</label>
            <select name="variedad">
                <option>Seleccione la variedad</option>
                <option>freedom</option>
                <option>vendela</option>
            </select>
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensajev" style='display: none;'>Seleccione la variedad</div>
            <label>Bonches</label>
            <input type="number" name="bonches" id="bonches" placeholder="Cantidad de bonches">
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensajeb" style='display: none;'>Digite el numero de bonches</div>
            <label>Unidades</label>
            <select id="unidades" name="unidades" onChange="mostrarl(this.value);" required="">
                <option>Seleccione las unidades</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
            </select>
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensajeu" style='display: none;'>Seleccione el numero de unidades por bonche</div>
            <label>Grado</label>
            <select required="" name="grado">
                <option>Seleccione el grado</option>
                <option>40</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>60</option>
                <option>70</option>
            </select>
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensajeg" style='display: none;'>Seleccione el grado</div>
            <label>Lámina</label>
            <select name="lamina">
                <option>Seleccione la lamina</option>
                <optgroup label="Lamina" id="lamina1" style='display: none;'>
                    <option>Benchmark</option>
                    <option>Golden</option>
                    <option>Microcorrugada</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Lamina" id="lamina2" style='display: none;'>
                    <option>Pet Transparante con papel</option>
                    <option>Transparante</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <div class="mensaje" id="mensajel" style='display: none;'>Seleccione la lamina</div>
            <button class="guardar" type="button" id="button-save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
            <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Y esta es mi función ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button-save').click(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'validarbonche' %}",
                data: {
                    bonches: $('#bonches').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
                },
                success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if ('valido' in response) {
                        if (response['valido']) {
                            $('#nboncheo').submit();
                            return true;
                        }else {
                            swal("El numero de bonches es mayor a los que hay actualmente");
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("no hay 'valido' en response");
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Si necesitas convertir el valor del atributo celda; puedes hacerlo con javascript de esta manera: `parseInt(celda)`

Answer (score 2):

Si estas segura que tu variable de `celda` siempre tendra numeros en dentro del string y solo tendrá numeros, entonces lo facil es usar la funcion `int()`

```
celda_string = '123'
celda_numero = int(celda_string)
print(type(celda_numero))
>>> <class 'int'>
print(celda_numero)
>>> 123
```

Ahora, si no sabes que recibiras exactamente en el post, que lo veo muy posible por las pocas validaciones que tienes, lo mejor es usar expresiones regulares acompañados de la funcion `int()`

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
celda_int = int(regex.findall('hola123')[0]) # puede tener letras, pero solo se tendran en cuenta los números
print(celda_int)
>>> 123
print(type(celda_int))
>>> <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que bastaría con la función `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

si validas correctamente que es un entero en el urls.py por ejemplo:

```
url(r'^test/view/(?P<celda>\d*)$', views.tuVista)
```

entonces vastaría con hacer

```
def tuVista(request, celda):
    celda = int(celda)
```

pero sin parámetros en la url (como lo tienes) sería algo como

```
def tuVista(request):
    celda = int(request.POST.get('bounches', 0))
```

no uses **None** pues en la función int te mostrará la excepción:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```